# How do I tabulate across an entire R data frame?

Tags: r

I've got a data frame containing, say, the columns `v1, v2, ..., v30` which contain the same factor variables, although the levels are different from column to column ('210N' under v3 might not appear under v5, for example - I'm not sure whether that is contributing to my trouble). Ideally, I'm hoping that, rather than doing a `table(df$v1)`, `table(df$v2)`, ... and onward to `table(df$v30)`, and adding up all the counts of the value I'm interested in, there's some kind of solution out there that performs the equivalent of `table(df$[, v1...v30])` - without requiring me to enforce the same levels across all columns, as in theory there should be around ~6000 levels in all.

So far, I've naively tried to merge a table on v1 with a table on v2, with `all=TRUE` set, although that doesn't do the trick: the the ensuing table contains two different counts for the same factor level, i.e, '210N' appears twice, but with different frequencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach to do this

```
table(unlist(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is

```
library(plyr)
llply(.data=df, .fun=table)
```